# Java 8.45 adding security exceptions without adding URL's to the security exception list

Tags: java, security

I'm in a company which is using alot of Java web applications. After the update of Java 8.45, everytime we try to open one of the java web applications, we get a security warning with the message:

[image]

When clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> on all of these prompts, the application just won't open. It gives the `"Error. Click for details"` error message.

It wouldn't be an option to add all the URL's, hostnames and IP addresses into the exception list, because that's just to much.

We're mostly using IE11.

Is there a way to bypass those security warnings?

Comment: May be you should resign your jars with new java

Comment: @Ilya What do you mean? The web applications are not ours to manage/edit.

Comment: @mhlz I dont really get it, the applications are not mine to manage/edit.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Java 8 requires all applets to be signed by a certificate authority. You can read more about that [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2014/01/16/still-using-applets-sign-them-or-else).

Comment: @Bas So application's owner should do it. Use old java version before they do it

Comment: So I have only 3 options, add them to the URL exception list, contact the  application owners or install a lower Java version?